# Data is not loading by useSWR. The data remains in loading state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, vercel

Today, I was using useSWR (by [zeit](https://swr.now.sh/)) hook for the first time, and I faced an issue that useSWR doesn't return data after fetching. I uploaded my front-end code on [git](https://github.com/mrpriyansh/useSwr-testing). My express server is running on http://34.66.137.51:4000 .You can verify it by requesting at endpoints "/" and "/testing." The code is below

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app=express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/testing',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('testing')
    res.status(200).json([{"nod":"hello"}, {"next":"hello1"}])
})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('asd')
    res.status(200).json('welcome');
});

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log("listening on 4000")
})
```

I assure you that the fetch function calls the server correctly as the server console shows *testing* as output. I want to know what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it so that *data* gets the response of the express server.

PS-Let me know if you are facing any problem in understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1** - Thanks to [Santiago Ignacio Poli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228407/santiago-ignacio-poli). He commented on a very efficient solution in the comment. I just quote it here so that you can go through it easily.

> The above code didn't work because you weren't wrapping your fetch
> code inside a function, so the code got executed immediately i.e () =>
> fetch(...)

**Old Solution**

I think only a few developers use useSWR, or my question is not much clear. Leave it whatever be the case, let's come to the solution.

Old **useSWR** part of App.js

```
const {data, error} = useSWR('http://34.66.137.51:4000/testing',fetch('http://34.66.137.51:4000/testing',{
method:'GET',
header:{ "Content-Type" : "applicaton/json"}
})
.then(response=>response.json())
```

);

I changed the **App.js** as below.

```
  const {data, error} = useSWR('http://34.66.137.51:4000/testing',fetcher);
```

and made fetcher.js as following

```
function fetcher(url) {
 return fetch(url, {
  headers: {
   Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 }).then(response => response.json());
}

export default fetcher;
```

By changing the files as above, I resolved my issue. I don't know why it's working or why that was not working! If anyone knows, then do the honor. Thank you.

Comment: The above code didn't work because you weren't wrapping your fetch code inside a function, so the code got executed inmediately i.e () => fetch(...)

Answer (score 1):

Another common pitfall: assigning to a different variable than `data` when using the `useSWR` hook.

```js
  const { rows, error } = useSWR('/api/example', fetcher)
```

This doesn't work because `useSWR` response object doesn't have a `rows` attribute. `rows` will keep being `undefined` even if the API returned the right response.

If you really want to map it to `rows`, you can do some destructuring:

```js
  const { data: rows, error } = useSWR('/api/example', fetcher)
```